# How to return to the start of a for loop?

Tags: c#

I'm working on the problem described below and I'm using a loop to solve it. I haven't got to classes yet. I need to restart the loop if incorrect data is entered.

In the If statement,

```
if (isInteger == false)
```

I can use a break statement to escape, but the rest of the for loop will execute and it'll restart and increment to i = 1. If the data type is wrong, I need it to go back to the start of the loop, where i= 0. How do I do it?

Challenge: Write a program that reads in 5 integer numbers from the user and prints their sum. If an invalid number is entered, the program should prompt the user to enter another number.

```
Console.WriteLine("This program accepts 5 integers from the user and returns their sum.\nIf an invalid integer is entered, the program notifies the user and asks for correct input.");

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter Integer {0} now.", (i + 1));
            string rawInput = Console.ReadLine();

            int integerSum = 0;

            int integerInput;
            bool isInteger = int.TryParse(rawInput, out integerInput);

            if (isInteger == false)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("This is not a valid integer. Please enter a valid integer now:");
                break;
            }
            else
            {                   
                integerSum += integerInput;                   
            }
        }
```

Comment: You may want to read into `continue`.

Comment: In addition to `continue`, realise that you can change the value of `i` _within_ the loop.

Comment: You may also want to have two loops, a `for` loop for the 5 values, and a `while`/`do-while` loop to ensure each value is an integer.

Comment: @Matthew Indeed - or swap the whole lot for a `while` loop that checks for `validNumbers.Count < 5`...

Comment: A more elegant solution would be to separate the "get one valid integer input" into a function, with the appropriate "retry if not valid" logic embedded. Then simply loop and call that function.

Comment: @akira Yep - there are many solutions.  The question being, at which point is the given answer going to look far too advanced for when the answer to the challenge is given...

Comment: @JamesThorpe - agreed, I put this as a comment rather than an answer for a reason. But the ex-TA in my can't help but react when I see students using convoluted and unnecessary looping logic.

Comment: Also, I can't help but feel like I should mention that [goto](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/13940fs2.aspx) would solve the problem too :)

Comment: Y'all some low hanging fruit picken mofos in hurr.

Comment: @ akira, I haven't learned about using methods and classes fully yet, so I'm supposed to solve it without using functions and classes yet. That's why I'm doing it procedurally.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Even without functions/classes, there are ways to implement this that do not require convoluted looping logic (breaking out of loops early, decrementing counters, etc.) I'm an ex-TA for intro CS courses and all of those make my eyebrows twitch. @Servy has an answer that covers this - the logic/flow is still valid even if you don't break it down into a separate function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look the c# keyword

> continue

Also you have a bug you are declaring

int integerSum = 0;

In the scope of your loop move that out of the loop otherwise you wont sum the numbers.

```
    Console.WriteLine("This program accepts 5 integers from the user and returns their sum.\nIf an invalid integer is entered, the program notifies the user and asks for correct input.");

    int integerSum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter Integer {0} now.", (i + 1));
        string rawInput = Console.ReadLine();



        int integerInput;
        bool isInteger = int.TryParse(rawInput, out integerInput);

        if (isInteger == false)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("This is not a valid integer. Please enter a valid integer now:");
            i--;                
            continue;
        }
        else
        {                   
            integerSum += integerInput;                   
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Result: " + integerSum);
```

Here are the details on continues:

> The continue statement passes control to the next iteration of the enclosing while, do, for, or foreach statement in which it appears.

```
class ContinueTest
{
 static void Main()
 {
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        if (i < 9)
        {
            continue;
        }
        Console.WriteLine(i);
    }

    // Keep the console open in debug mode.
    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
    Console.ReadKey();
   }
}
/*
Output:
9
10
*/
```

[MSDN further details](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/923ahwt1.aspx)

Comment: Won't using the continue statement just restart the for loop again at i = 1? Unless I took James Thorpe's advice and decremented i. Edit: I see how you did it.

Comment: yes you had break which exits the loop continue goes back to the loop that wont work.  With your current approach you need to decrement i if you go with the for loop with i as an iterator and use continue.  There are many solutions to this problem.  while(true)  etc etc etc

Answer (score 5):

Use continue like this

```
if (isInteger == false)
{
   Console.WriteLine("This is not a valid integer. Please enter a valid integer now:");
   i--;
   continue;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This should do it:

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        int sum = 0, value = 0;

        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter Integer {0} now.", i);

            while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out value))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("This is not a valid integer. Please enter a valid integer {0} now:", i);
            }

            sum += value;
        }

        Console.WriteLine(sum);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't simply return to the top of the loop with `continue`, because you would end up making fewer iterations than it is necessary.

You have several choices here:

1. Decrement `i` and use `continue`, or
2. Remove `i++` from the loop header, and move it into the end of the loop body, or
3. Do the #2, and also switch to a `while` loop for better clarity.

The first two choices shoehorn the code into `for` loop. I think a `while` loop would be better:

```
int i = 0;
int integerSum = 0;
while (i != 5) {
     Console.WriteLine("Please enter Integer {0} now.", (i + 1));
     string rawInput = Console.ReadLine();
     int integerInput;
     if (!int.TryParse(rawInput, out integerInput)) {
         Console.WriteLine("This is not a valid integer. Please enter a valid integer now:");
         continue;
     }
     integerSum += integerInput;                   
     i++;
}
```

Don't forget to move `integerSum` out of the loop!

Comment: Why is there "!" in front of the int.TryParse method?

Comment: I forgot about that. I hadn't seen it used with methods.

Answer (score 2):

the answer! soon you will be a mega rich l33t coder

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            int integerSum = 0;
            int count = 0;
            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter Integer {0} now.", (count + 1));
                string rawInput = Console.ReadLine();

                int integerInput;
                bool isInteger = int.TryParse(rawInput, out integerInput);

                if (isInteger == false)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("This is not a valid integer. Please enter a valid integer now:");
                }
                else
                {
                    integerSum += integerInput;
                    count ++;
                }
                if (count >= 5)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("sum = " + integerSum);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for solving it in a completely different way. I hadn't thought about solving it like this.

Answer (score 2):

Currently you're trying to do too much in one operation.  You should separate out the "Get a valid value from the user, no matter how many tries it takes" from the "get 5 valid values from the user" operation.

```
private static int SumFiveInts()
{
    Console.WriteLine("This program accepts 5 integers from the user and returns their sum.\nIf an invalid integer is entered, the program notifies the user and asks for correct input.");

    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        sum += GetIntegerFromConsole(i);
    }
    return sum;
}
public static int GetIntegerFromConsole(int attempt)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter Integer {0} now.", (attempt + 1));
    int output;
    while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out output))
        Console.WriteLine("This is not a valid integer. Please enter a valid integer now:");
    return output;
}
```

Comment: I don't know how to use methods or classes yet. Edit: But thanks for this, I wanted to know how to do this with proper methods and structure.

Comment: @Code_Steel Well, it's impossible to ever write a compilable executable C# program without doing both of those things, so you should know *something* about them.  And now would be as good a time as any to begin to learn something about them if you really do know nothing.  Personally I'd say that what you see in most of the other answers here is quite a lot *more* complex and *harder* to understand than creating a new method is.

Comment: No I know about their theory, but I haven't got to chapter where I start working on them. I don't understand these lines at all, can you explain them? And what's attempt? Is that an input value?

    int output;
    while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out output))

Comment: @Code_Steel `attempt` is the parameter to the method, yes.  As I said, if you haven't learned anything about methods now's a great time to start.  You're at the point where the code you're trying to write would benefit greatly from having multiple methods, and you'll only make things *harder* on yourself by not using them to some extent.

Answer (score 0):

i know it's been a while and the post is long,i found a simpler way of writing this code..

```
 int integerSum = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 5;)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter Integer {0} now.", (i + 1));
            string rawInput = Console.ReadLine();

            int integerInput;
            bool isInteger = int.TryParse(rawInput, out integerInput);

            if (isInteger == false)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("This is not a valid integer. Please enter a valid integer now:");

            }
            else if (isInteger == true)
            {
                integerSum += integerInput;
                i++;
            }

        }
        Console.WriteLine("The sum of all number entered is:{1}{0} ", integerSum, Environment.NewLine);
```